# Sqlite3 Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT) error

Tags: sqlite

i read about this and i think it is something about this value might be nil and you cant assert something to nil bla bla bla, well i tried to check if this sqlite3_bind_text != sqlite_ok i tried guard but nothing seems to work. need help please!

```
func insert(_ name: String = "",_ image: String = "",_ ingredients:String = "", instructions:String = ""){
    var stmt:OpaquePointer?
    let query = "INSERT INTO Recipe (name,image,ingredients,instructions) VALUES(?,?,?,?)"
    if sqlite3_prepare(db,query, -1,&stmt,nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        sqlite3_bind_text(db, 1, name, -1, nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(db,2,image,-1,nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(db,3,ingredients,-1,nil)
        sqlite3_bind_text(db,4,instructions,-1,nil)
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nvm solved in

```
sqlite3_bind_text(db, 1, name, -1, nil)
sqlite3_bind_text(db,2,image,-1,nil)
sqlite3_bind_text(db,3,ingredients,-1,nil)
sqlite3_bind_text(db,4,instructions,-1,nil)
```

db should have been replaced with stmt instead dunno why

```
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, 1, name, -1, nil)
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,2,image,-1,nil)
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,3,ingredients,-1,nil)
sqlite3_bind_text(stmt,4,instructions,-1,nil)
```